# why MyDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") is return "MM/dd/yyyy format?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am converting a date with `MyDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` but it returns my date with a `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

My code:

```
cell.InnerText += "Created Between " +
                  this.BetweenAndStrat.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " And " +
                  this.BetweenAndEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Are you sure the date was *created* correctly? Also, I understand that it's urgent for you, but you have to understand that *everyone* wants their questions answered (if they didn't, they wouldn't be posting here).

Comment: show complete code, there must be something wrong elsewhere

Comment: cell.InnerText += "Created Between " + this.BetweenAndStrat.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " And " + this.BetweenAndEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: I believe @WajidAli was asking for you to show the code that created the values put in `BetweenAndStrat` and `BetweenAndEnd`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a date in a string with the format "MM/dd/yyyy" and want to convert it to "dd/MM/yyyy" you could do like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var date = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", MyDate);
```

Comment: try this, and be sure that you have specified your culture in the webconfig: `<globalization uiCulture="xx-xx" culture="xx-xx" fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />`